# Blender 3.5 keyboard layout changes automatically

Tags: shortcut

Hi guys i came across this weird problem.
My keyboard is azerty and i dont have any other layout installed
the layout changes only when i try to rename an object it writes in arabic letters
the axes and the shortcuts of blender are all fine the only problem is when try to rename something.